# angular directive replace newline with html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a service to retrieve data which binds to the html like this

```
{{order.Notes}}
```

order.Notes may contain multi-line text so i would like to format it using html tags 'br'

This is the directive i'm trying to use:

```
angular.module('directives', [])

.directive('htmlText', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>',
    scope: {
        text: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        var updateText = function () {

            if (scope.text != null) {
                scope.html = scope.text.replace('\n', "<br/>");
            }
        };

        scope.$watch('text', function (oldVal, newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                updateText();
            }
        });
    }
};
});

<html-text text="order.Notes"></html-text>
```

however, newVal is always null. what am i missing here?

Comment: The watch function takes newVal as first argument, you have provided the second.

Comment: ok, thanks. But the binding is not working 
template: '<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>'

Comment: <div ng-bind-html="html"></div>

this works!